# Corona SDK: show emoji/images on native.showAlert()

Tags: coronasdk

I'd like to let a user know on my game that he's won a life by showing some text with a little heart on the end through native.showAlert().

the code for the alert is

```
native.showAlert( "Hi!", "Thank you for playing! Here's one extra life as a gift for your next game. Enjoy!" , {"OK"}, lifegift )
```

I want to show a heart after enjoy. How do I do that? It could be either emoji or an image. Thanks

p.s.: only building for iOS for now

Comment: You are going to have to add more information to your questions. What do you have currently? What have you tried? Your question right now could be answered by? "Yes, there is a way to do that"

Comment: @Frozire I added the code for the alert. I want to show a little heart after enjoy on the alert text. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you simply want to show a heart on your corona SDK alert..?
If you are using a mac, then you can simply do this as:

```
native.showAlert( "Hi!", "You got an extra ♥ " , {"OK"}, lifegift )
```

It will look like this:

[image]

You can get different symbols from various sites like [this](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/444-how-to-use-html-character-entities-to-display-symbols-and-characters-in-html-documents/).

Keep coding........... :)

Comment: Thank You! It works great. Is there anyway to make it bigger?

Comment: @dietbacon: I don't think corona provides such features. So, you may have to create a custom alert view using images and labels.